# Get variable of Keyboard type

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, xcode4.5

I have been trying to get the variable for the keyboardType
`self.titleField.keyboardType`
When i use nslog it returns about 10 values that are either 0 or 4

I have implemented custom behavior for the number pad keyboard so i need to check if it's the number pad or default keyboard that is showing up.
I have also tried to use `self.view.tag` to set it by view instead of keyboard.
The nslog for that returns all the tags of the previous view controllers that the application
has been through.

I think this may be because i'm reusing a single view controller class for each separate
controller. I am using a switch statements to determine what 
data to display based on the tag.

Is their a way to reset the tag in `viewWillDisappear`?

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning tag value to textfields and check which textfield became first responder in TF's delegate method `-textFieldDidBeginEditing:`

Answer (score 0):

The `UIKeyboardType` enumeration gives names to the keyboard type numbers:

```
switch (self.titleField.keyboardType) {
    case UIKeyboardTypeDefault:
        NSLog(@"default keyboard");
        break;
    case UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad:
        NSLog(@"number pad keyboard");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"unexpected keyboard type %d", self.titleField.keyboardType);
        break;
}
```